# In control flow graphs, what is the difference between a path and a branch?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, software-testing

I'm studying for an exam on software testing and in my notes I found this:

```
Many more paths than branches. A pragmatic compromise will be needed
```

I cannot understand the difference between paths and branches; each time I work out the paths and branches of a graph I end up with the same number. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the exact definitions used by your class, so I am saying this with caution. A branch normally correspnds to a graph edge that allows control to pass from one node to another in the graph. A path is a succession of edges connected to each other, with possible repetition and representing the successive parts traversed by the control. So a branch will be a element of the program structure, a static entity. The path represent a fragment of computation.

If you say more about what you understood, I may be able to tell you whether it makes sense.

Comment: Well from what you're saying I think that a branch is a point in a program where execution can take two or more different paths such as an if-then-else statement, with a path being the flow of execution taken if that particular condition is met. I also have written that a path is "a sequence of branches".

Comment: Answer and Comment corrected (I was saying vertex for edge ... sorry) ...Well, I checked a bit, and it seems that some people talk about branch
only when the possible flow branches, i.e., can take different
edges. Typically this is a conditionnal. Other Use that word also for
edges that will just go to another node (corresponding approximately
to a goto statement - but that does not seem essential). A path can
indeed be defined as a sequence of branches since it defines uniquely
a computation fragment, independently of nodes that have several in
edges and a single out edge.